# this dlsym call runs into a segfault (when caller .so is the same as target .so)

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, dlsym

First, the problem:

```
Thread 2 "lexe.exe" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff2c89700 (LWP 17367)]
do_lookup_x (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", new_hash=new_hash@entry=1920857680, old_hash=old_hash@entry=0x7ffff2c88460, ref=0x0, result=result@entry=0x7ffff2c88470, 
    scope=0x1800029030008080, i=0, version=0x0, flags=2, skip=0x0, type_class=0, undef_map=0x7ffff2c8a000) at dl-lookup.c:339
339 dl-lookup.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  do_lookup_x (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", new_hash=new_hash@entry=1920857680, old_hash=old_hash@entry=0x7ffff2c88460, ref=0x0, result=result@entry=0x7ffff2c88470, 
    scope=0x1800029030008080, i=0, version=0x0, flags=2, skip=0x0, type_class=0, undef_map=0x7ffff2c8a000) at dl-lookup.c:339
#1  0x00007ffff7de023f in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", undef_map=0x7ffff2c8a000, ref=0x7ffff2c88528, symbol_scope=0x7ffff2c8a388, version=0x0, type_class=0, flags=2, 
    skip_map=<optimized out>) at dl-lookup.c:813
#2  0x00007ffff698bfe6 in do_sym (flags=<optimized out>, vers=0x0, who=0x7ffff2db36e9 <loadLibFunc2+248>, name=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", handle=0x7ffff2c8a000) at dl-sym.c:151
#3  _dl_sym (handle=0x7ffff2c8a000, name=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", who=0x7ffff2db36e9 <loadLibFunc2+248>) at dl-sym.c:254
#4  0x00007ffff6c170e4 in dlsym_doit (a=a@entry=0x7ffff2c88770) at dlsym.c:50
#5  0x00007ffff698c51f in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7ffff2c88700, operate=0x7ffff6c170d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=0x7ffff2c88770) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#6  0x00007ffff698c5af in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x603000000020, errstring=0x603000000028, mallocedp=0x603000000018, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#7  0x00007ffff6c17745 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff6c170d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7ffff2c88770) at dlerror.c:162
#8  0x00007ffff6c17166 in __dlsym (handle=<optimized out>, name=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI") at dlsym.c:70
#9  0x00007ffff2db36e9 in loadLibFunc2 (T=0x7ffff30ff064, PVLib=0x7ffff2c8a000, FuncName=0x7fffeb893ad9 "algoLenI", Check=0 '\000') at ../loadLib/loadLib.c:206


void* loadLibFunc2(void* T, void* PVLib, char* FuncName, bool Check) {
    // ... checked PVLib not null
    void* Res = dlsym(PVLib, FuncName);
    // ... further code that is not reached
}
```

clean-recompiling both loader and library with `-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer` did not show any errors.

Valgrind:

```
==10456== Invalid read of size 4
==10456==    at 0x400A2A1: do_lookup_x (dl-lookup.c:339)
==10456==    by 0x400B23E: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (dl-lookup.c:813)
==10456==    by 0x51A6FE5: do_sym (dl-sym.c:151)
==10456==    by 0x51A6FE5: _dl_sym (dl-sym.c:254)
==10456==    by 0x4E3D0E3: dlsym_doit (dlsym.c:50)
==10456==    by 0x51A751E: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==10456==    by 0x51A75AE: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==10456==    by 0x4E3D744: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:162)
==10456==    by 0x4E3D165: dlsym (dlsym.c:70)
==10456==    by 0x5CFE821: loadLibFunc2 (loadLib.c:206)
```

It looks like dlsym has the proper inputs:

```
(gdb) x/8xb PVLib
0x7ffff6e04000: 0x7f    0x45    0x4c    0x46    0x02    0x01    0x01    0x00
```

That looks like the start of the library

```
(gdb) x/8xb (char*)PVLib+0x919a7
0x7ffff6e959a7 <algoLenI>:  0x55    0x48    0x89    0xe5    0x48    0x83    0xec    0x10
```

That looks like the start of algoLenI, and GDB even identifies it.

Does dlsym get confused because the main program also has an algoLenI?:

```
(gdb) p algoLenI
$4 = {int32 (void *, charC *)} 0x555555566e81 <algoLenI>
(gdb) x/8xb 0x555555566e81
0x555555566e81 <algoLenI>:  0x55    0x48    0x89    0xe5    0x48    0x83    0xec    0x10
```

A reason might be that the caller of dlsym is already code from that same .so: the loader executable loads the .so, then some code inside the .so indirectly also needs to dlsym. This should not be a problem though because dlsym seems to have the correct arguments (see above).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that under certain conditions, the pointer to the library was dereferenced elsewhere.

The library-pointer should not point to something like this (corresponds to the file's beginning)

```
0x7f    0x45    0x4c    0x46    0x02    0x01    0x01    0x00
```

but to an opaque handle returned by dlopen. That the indirection got us to something corresponding to the file's content is just "concidence": that the opaque handle starts with with a pointer to the former on this operating system.